# RecyclerView(x2) и Child с Parent

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout

Хотел бы сделать список из двух RecyclerView (один для ParentItem, а другой для ChildItem) Например у нас есть ParentItem (Спорт), а у него есть ChildItem (футбол, баскетбол, хоккей). Не могу правильно реализовать данную идею. 
+ ко всему есть еще два Лэйаута в которых по TextView (1 - для Parent, 2 - для Child). Выглядит это так: Parent(Со своим RecyclerView и TextView(он в Лэйауте)), а ниже выстраивается Child (тоже со своим RecyclerView и TextView). Никто не знает, как можно реализовать данную идею?

Comment: покажите на примере, что вам надо. Словами не понятно.

Comment: Как можно реализовать список интересов, при нажатии на какой либо интерес срабатывает слушатель и раскрывает его детей. Например выбрал интерес (Спорт), нажал на него и появились его дети (Футбол, баскетбол итд...).

Comment: https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view оно?

Comment: вот тут с примером ,как работает: http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо)